# How to create durable queue using Artemis JMS Management API

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

It's a long story  but I need to create a *durable* queue using the Artemis JMS  Management API. Currently the code creates a temporary queue as a default:

```
JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation("jms.server", "createQueue", "MyqueueName", null, null, true);
```

I think the original author assumed this would create a durable queue but  apparently not. I can't find good documentation on this and was wondering if anybody could confirm/deny this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for this is https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/management.html or [management.md](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/docs/user-manual/en/management.md) in GitHub. Then there is [the API doc](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/package-summary.html) to find the details.

Looking at https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html#createQueue-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String- the method you want to call is

```
createQueue(String address, String name, String filter, boolean durable)
```

Documentation says

> If address is null it will be defaulted to name.

You are setting `name` to null, not `address`. If I instead run

```
JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation("0.0.0.0", "createQueue", null, "MyqueueName", null, true);
```

that does not work either. I believe it is a bug. Will investigate more and report that.

So I duplicate the queue name

```
JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation("0.0.0.0", "createQueue", "MyqueueName", "MyqueueName", null, true);
```

and now I correctly get a durable queue.

Comment: Reported as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1456. I believe https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1282 may also be relevant.